# How can I have a single calendar for all Trello cards?

Tags: trello

I intend to use Trello for my personal new years bucket list task manager.

1. At a high level there are a number of goals (cards).
2. At the secondary level, I  will have multiple cards associated with goals.
3. I also have calendar entry to to work on each goal (card) on daily basis.

Is it possible to see all my daily tasks/cards across multiple boards  in a single Trello calendar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sunrise Calendar](https://calendar.sunrise.am/), which was recently acquired by Microsoft, offers a Trello integration that allows you to aggregate cards with due dates on to a calendar.

You may need to install and configure the Trello integration via the Sunrise mobile app first, before having access to it on the desktop.

Once configured, you'll have the option of selecting `My Cards` or you can choose to select cards from specific boards.

[image: Sunrise Calendar Trello Integration]

If you use Google Chrome (Chromium), you can install the [Sunrise Calendar Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sunrise-calendar/mojepfklcankkmikonjlnidiooanmpbb?hl=en).

**Caveats**

- The Sunrise Calendar app will [no longer be updated](http://blog.sunrise.am/post/132088346354/this-is-just-the-beginning-part-2) as the app development focus has now shifted to Microsoft's [Outlook](https://blogs.office.com/2015/10/28/outlook-for-ios-and-android-gains-momentum-gets-new-look/) product.
- The Trello events that display on Sunrise Calendar default to 1 hour events.

Comment: @SJ2K Great. Let us know if you are successful.

Comment: Hi Rahi, reporting back. Sunrise has worked seamlessly with Trello and I have a perfect view of all Trello deliverables on Sunrise calendar. Any chance that I can use Trello for recurring tasks ?

Comment: @SJ2K Glad to hear. Please consider *accepting* the answer to your question. With regards to creating recurring tasks, it's a separate question, and it has been [asked before](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/33886/24161). Going with an [IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/299813-schedule-daily-or-weekly-recurring-trello-cards) is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

As Sunrise is maybe not an option forever: you can get the iCal feed from each board and import it into a 3rd party calendar like Google calendar.

See: http://help.trello.com/article/811-viewing-cards-in-a-calendar-view

Comment: thanks. Please see my comment above, Sunrise works perfectly with Trello tasks.No need to use any other ical feed .

Comment: @SJ2K thanks, the mention was for a time that is coming up when sunrise isn't there anymore. This as the company along with sunrise has been bought up by Microsoft. However for now I am happy to read sunrise is working as it should, as it does with me

Comment: Time flies. Sunrise has worked wonderfully well but unfortunately it is being 'sunset' (no pun intended) 8/31.  is there any alternate calendar to sunrise that will integrate trello events ? Do  outlook for iphone  be used for this purpose ?